# Quadratic Equation, cannot figure out syntax error

Tags: java

I am working on a school assignment. I am supposed to implement a class and supply the methods getSolution1 and getSolution2. However, I am having 2 issues with my code that I cannot figure out.

Issue #1 is on this line:

```
solution1= ((-1*b)/> + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c)));
```

The compiler is telling me: Syntax error on token ">", delete this token. I can't figure out if I am doing something wrong on my syntax.

Issue #2 is on the ouput line:

```
String quadEquation= "The quadratic equation is "+ a + Math.pow(("x"),2) + " + " + b+"x"+ " + " + c+ " =0";
```

Under the Math.pow I get an error that says: The Method pow is not applicable for the arguments String

Here is my entire code:

```
       public class QuadraticEquation

{

  double a;
  double b;
  double c;
  double solution1;
  double solution2;

QuadraticEquation (double a, double b, double c){

     a= this.a;
     b= this.b;
     c= this.c;
}

public boolean hasSolution (){

  if ((Math.pow(b,2))- (4*a*c)<0){

    return false;
  }

  else

  {
    return true;
  }
}

 public double getSolution1 (double a, double b, double c)

{

  if (hasSolution){

      solution1= ((-1*b) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c))) / 2*a;

    return solution1;

  }

}

 public double getSolution2 (double a, double b, double c){

    if (hasSolution){

        solution1= ((-1*b) - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c))) / 2*a;
    return solution2;
}

}

public String toString (double a, double b, double c){

    String quadEquation= "The quadratic equation is "+ a + "x^2" + " + " + b+"x"+ " + " + c+ " =0";

    return quadEquation;

  }

}
```

Since this is a school assignment, I am looking for guidance on solving this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for explanation and being honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
solution1= ((-1*b) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c))) / 2*a;
```

There is no such thing as a `/>` in Java.

```
String quadEquation= "The quadratic equation is "+ a + "x^2" + " + " + b+"x"+ " + " + c+ " =0";
```

Math.pow requires numbers whereas you were passing the string "x". the symbol "^" is generally used to say to the power of , therefore x^2 is x to the power of 2. I do not think there is a simple solution to write superscript in standard output.

Java cannot understand what to return if the equation has no solution

```
public double getSolution2 (double a, double b, double c){

    if (hasSolution){
        solution1= ((-1*b) - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c))) / 2*a;
        return solution2;
    }
    return -1; // or throw an exception.
}
```

returning -1 will fix it.

Comment: Thank you, when I made the change it got rid of the error. But as I made that change I realized that this line:                       public double getSolution1 (double a, double b, double c, boolean hasSolution) was incorrect. it would not return a value of double. so I got rid off boolean hasSolution. but now my statement if (hasSolution) is saying that is not initialized.

Comment: @user2559274 i am not sure what you mean by that. returning a double is perfectly reasonable. Why did you think that line was incorrect.Add the new code to the question so that I might be able to answer. Just a couple of things.. if ( hasSolution ) should be enough.. no need for "== true". Furthermore define solution1 and solution2 inside methods instead of the class. you dont even need variables . you can simply do `return ((-1*b)/> - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c)));`

Comment: Thank you, now that I see it, it seems rather obvious. But it eluded me for a couple of days. I appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 8):

Your first issue is that you can't use /> together. This is not a proper operation. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Second issue is because Math.pow requires two numbers. You have a string in there. It would be like trying to get the power of the word apple. You cant do it. You must first convert that string into an int. [How to convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java)